# C# setter unknown field

Tags: java, c#

I found an example for my solution in C# as follows:

```
address.streetName = new[] {
    new adxpstreetName {Text = new[] {ausAddress.StreetName}}
};
```

With my limited knowledge of C#, the above tells me that **adxpstreetName** object is constructed and **ausAddress.StreetName** is injected to it. What puzzles me is to which field the value is injected to.

The adxpstreetName is generated from XSD that does not have field **streetName**.

I am required to provide the solution in Java and the above seems like Javascript where you can introduce a new field as you like.
Can C# experts help enlighten me?
Thank you

Comment: Whoever wrote that needs some lessons on readable code.

Comment: and whoever asked this question needs some lessons in reading docs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about functionality that is clearly documented.

Comment: ... care to share the link to the documentation you are talking about as I am totally new to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- a new `adxpstreetName[]` array is created of length 1, and populated with a new `adxpstreetName` instance
- a new `string[]` array is created of length 1, and populated with the value from `ausAddress.StreetName`
- this `string[]` is assigned to the `Text` property / field of the `adxpstreetName` instance
- the `adxpstreetName[]` array is assigned to the `streetName` property / field of the `address` instance

If you want to know where `streetName` is declared: put the caret into `streetName` and press f12 (in visual studio; similar shortcuts exist in other IDEs)

If `address` is declared as `dynamic`, then things can be more... *interesting*. Is `address` declared as `dynamic`?

Comment: Thanks, Marc, what I asked originally was your point3, which adxpstreetName's field is the string[] inserted to? I have to make Java-equivalent of it adxpstreetName.??? = String[] {ausAddress.StreetName}, I am not sure what Text field is (That is not in the XSD).

Comment: @user3736872 "this `string[]` is assigned to the `Text` property / field of the `adxpstreetName` instance". So: move to `Text`, and press F12 (or right-click and "show definition")